# Replicate heroku/node.js memory leak on local server for debugging

Tags: node.js, heroku, memory-leaks, profiling

How can I replicate a memory issue on Heroku locally for debugging?  Or better profile memory use on Heroku?

I have a Node.js application on Heroku.   One server side utility does a bunch of 
work to generate a file for download for user projects.  For one particularly large case, after a few exercises Heroku yields the following warnings:

```
Process running mem=529M(103.4%)
2015-01-24T02:23:18.240108+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2015-01-24T02:23:18.240108+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=529M(103.4%)
...
```

After each additional exercise, the memory use goes up, so it looks to me like a sure leak:

```
2015-01-24T02:31:22.321689+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=747M(145.9%)
2015-01-24T02:31:22.321689+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2015-01-24T02:31:44.523511+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=747M(145.9%)
2015-01-24T02:31:44.523800+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2015-01-24T02:32:06.296071+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=747M(145.9%)
2015-01-24T02:32:06.296314+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
```

But I'm unable to replicate this locally.

Running profiling tools `v8-profiler` and `node-inspector` per https://github.com/felixge/node-memory-leak-tutorial, the Heap usage briefly spikes to 156MB on each exercise but comes right back to way under 1MB.  I can call that utility endlessly and get the same result without a memory error.

At a minimum, what are the right options for limiting memory use?  The doc says this option is specified in bytes, but the application works without complaint using the following, so I suspect the option is being ignored:

```
node --debug --max-stack-size=512 app
```

Comment: Care to share the code that is causing the memory leak?

Comment: If only I could find that bit!  Tried a few times to isolate a modest subset that causes the error but then the phenomenon disappears.

Answer (score 0):

While `node --help` suggests `--max-stack-size=[bytes]` on the first screen, the argument to limit mem usage is `--max-old-space-size=[Mbytes]`.

```
 node --max-old-space-size=512 app.js
```

That was enough to recreate the out of memory error locally.